# Embedded. H2 DB Auto Increment (Java Test Case)

Tags: java, junit, h2

I have a Java Spring Application which has a MS SQL DB. For unit testing the DAO classes I'm using Embedded H2 DB to insert some dummy data into the H2 DB. But I'm struggling to get auto generation of the primary key working.

This is the create schema/table/Insert dummy data queries which is in a create.sql file in the resources folder in my Spring project dir :

```
CREATE SCHEMA local_db AUTHORIZATION sa; 
CREATE TABLE local_db.test_db (
  id int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  isActive varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Inserting dummy data

```
INSERT INTO local_db.test_db VALUES (1,'TestDATA1','Y');
INSERT INTO local_db.test_db VALUES (2,'TestDATA2','Y');
INSERT INTO local_db.test_db VALUES (3,'TestDATA3','Y');
```

My test code reading this create.sql file which is creating the schema / table correctly with the dummy data.

This is done in the test class setUp()

```
DaoClassUnderTest daoClassUnderTest;
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedDatabase db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().
    setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).
    addScript("create.sql").
    build(); 
    daoClassUnderTest  = new DaoClassUnderTest(db);
  }
```

But when I actually call the insert method on the DAO class (which is being tested), it inserts the data but it leaves the id field null without inserting any value in the id column.

```
INSERT INTO local_db.test_db (username, isActive) VALUES (?,?);
```

How can I have the Auto increment working on the Embedded.H2 DB from the Junit test code?

Comment: Please do not add things like _[SOLVED]_ to a question title. I have rolled back that edit. Either post an **answer** with your solution, or delete your question.

Comment: Yup just did that.

Answer (score 0):

Worked after I modified the create table query as

```
CREATE TABLE local_db.test_db (
  id int(4) NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  username varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  isActive varchar(1) NOT NULL
);
```